# Is it necessary to use Forever.js on OpenShift?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift, forever

I've deployed my first Node.js app on OpenShift's free tier, and it works great.

Will OpenShift automatically restart my Node app when it crashes, or do I have to set up Forever.js? I tried setting it up, and it would not work. After running `node_modules/forever/bin/forever start app.js` (working dir was `app-root/repo`, with local copy of `forever`) I got this output:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js

fs.js:240
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/var/lib/openshift/5397416f5004466c0b000080/.forever/VQMF.log'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:240:18)
    at Object.startDaemon (/var/lib/openshift/5397416f5004466c0b000080/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:406:14)
    at /var/lib/openshift/5397416f5004466c0b000080/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:258:13
    at /var/lib/openshift/5397416f5004466c0b000080/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:145:5
    at Object.oncomplete (/var/lib/openshift/5397416f5004466c0b000080/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:358:11)
```

So, does OpenShift manage my app's health for me, or will I need to get Forever working? If so, any idea as to the error I got?

Comment: Perfect question, exactly what I need to know moving over from Modulus (which also restarts your app).  Modulus also has the option to send you an email, anybody know if OpenShift can do that?  (It doesn't look like node-supervisor has that option)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, OpenShift does automatically restart your Node app when it crashes.  OpenShift doesn't use forever.js but it uses [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor).  Your can test it by requiring something that doesn't exist.  Fix it quick though because the log can grow fast restarting the app.  Here is the log in nodejs.log on OpenShift which shows that it's running node-supervisor:

```
DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with
DEBUG:   program 'server.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/53a9e06ae0b8cde26300008e/app-root/data/.nodewatch'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
DEBUG: Watching directory '/var/lib/openshift/53a9e06ae0b8cde26300008e/app-root/data/.nodewatch' for changes.
```

Comment: Interesting, where is that log at? And does it use `main` or `scripts.start` for this?

Comment: ssh onto the system using the command string from openshift site under your app.  Then cd app-root/logs, all the logs are there.  I'm sure they are using script to deploy since there are so many things started/installed/setup before starting the app... I haven't really digged into it to see which script it is though.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, OpenShift's default behavior involves using `supervisor` to start, watch, and restart your nodejs applications.

Here is a quick outline of the various init options for nodejs:

1. If your app includes a valid `package.json` file with a `main` entry ([containing the name of your server script](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#main)), then OpenShift will initialize your app by using `supervisor` to start that script.
2. If your app includes the [`force_npm_deploy` marker file](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-release-for-february-2014) (an empty file in `.openshift/markers/use_npm`) - then OpenShift will just run `npm start`.  This runs whatever is defined in your `package.json` file's `scripts.start` entity.
3. If all else fails, OpenShift will try to run `server.js` using `supervisor` (as a fallback option).

Some additional notes are available here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/10-reasons-openshift-is-the-best-place-to-host-your-nodejs-app#npm